# Как обновить селектор в jQuery после AJAX запроса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, frontend

Имеется таблица с данными внутри основного блока, при первой загрузке таблицы, взаимодействовать с ней можно с помощью jquery.

Но используя AJAX, я хочу динамически менять таблицу, вот как я это делаю:

```
filter_data = {/*Тут мои данные*/}
$.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "URL",
                data: filter_data,
                success: function (result) {
                    var $main_block = $(".main-block");
                    $main_block.html("");
                    $main_block.html(result);
                },
                error: function (error) {

                }
            });
```

При успешном запросе, сервер возвращает отрендеренный html, где я стираю старую таблицу, и обновляю ее новой.

но после этих действий jQuery не понимает что были изменения в коде и например взаимодействовать с полем класс которого `version` невозможно как это было до AJAX запроса.

Внизу вполне при запуске именно эта проблема:

До изменений клик на поле **Version** показывает версию, но после изменений уже нет.

```js
$(".version").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});

function update() {
  filter_data = { /*Тут мои данные*/ }
  // Манипулируем AJAX запрос на отработку в ERROR
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "URL",
    data: filter_data,
    success: function(result) {
      alert("НЕ РАБОТАЕТ");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      var $main_block = $(".main-block");
      $main_block.html("");
      $main_block.html('<table border=1> <tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Version</th> </tr> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>Voogy</td> <td class="version">55.0.0</td> </tr> <tr> <td>2</td> <td>Piggy</td> <td class="version">26.16.1</td> </tr> <tr> <td>3</td> <td>Smoogy</td> <td class="version">14.67.5</td> </tr> </table>');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-block">
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Version</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Voogy</td>
      <td class="version">1.0.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Piggy</td>
      <td class="version">2.1.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Smoogy</td>
      <td class="version">1.6.5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button onclick="update()">Update table</button>
```

Не могу понять что тут нужно делать чтобы `selector` обновился.

Comment: уже неоднократно задавался вопрос

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо вам большое, именно то что нужно было!!!